# SSL fatal error

Tags: java, ssl

I tried to access the third party API, but I am getting below error.
I enabled the SSL debug and I found the below error.

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have installed the JCE limited and un-limited policy but still I am facing the issue.

I am using  jdk1.8.0_161.

Comment: Given that your question does not provide any details which might distinguish it from the many similar questions I've marked it as duplicate of one of these.

Comment: I have followed the same step and import the certificate file into cacerts. But still I face the issue. Another point here is I am not getting this issue continuously. Some times only getting. Please advice.